# Add values with key and value pair in the list in Java

Tags: java, list

I have this list
  `"DailyQuantity": [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,4,4,4]`

So I want to add like

`"DailyQuantity": [{"one" , 0},{"two" , 0},{"three" , 0},{"four" , 0},{"five" , 0},{"six" , 0},{"seven" , 0},{"eight" , 1},{"nine" , 3},{"ten" , 4},{"eleven" , 4},{"twelve" , 4}]`

Comment: Whenever you post a question, you should always post whatever code you have tried.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this answers your question, but you could try using a map:

```
Map<String,Integer> DailyQuantity = new HashMap<String, Integer>();
DailyQuantity.put("one",0);
DailyQuantity.put("two",0);
...
```

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to provide a list/array of numeral words (and/or generator method for numbers > 20) and use it to create a map.

If you need to keep the order of insertion, you should use `LinkedHashMap`.

```
final List<String> numeralsTo20 = Arrays.asList(
    "zero", "one", "two", "three", "four", 
    "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine",
    "ten", "eleven", "twelve"// etc..
);

// should be retrieved from JSON
List<Integer> dailyQuantity = Arrays.asList(0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,3,4,4,4);

Map<String, Integer> quantityMap = IntStream.range(0, dailyQuantity.size()) // get stream of int indexes
     .boxed()                      // convert to Integer objects
     .collect(Collectors.toMap(
         i -> numeralsTo20.get(i + 1), // key
         i -> dailyQuantity.get(i),    // quantity value
         (o1, o2) -> o2,               // merge function to add new entry
         LinkedHashMap::new));         // LinkedHashMap maintains insertion order

quantityMap.entrySet().forEach(System.out::println);

// quantityMap should be serialized back to JSON
```

output:

```
one=0
two=0
three=0
four=0
five=0
six=0
seven=0
eight=1
nine=3
ten=4
eleven=4
twelve=4
```